# Vertical ListView in Horizontal ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

What's the best approach to get such a result in WPF?
To embedd a vertical listview per listviewitem in a horizontal listview?

Thanks for your efforts.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so could you post your code.

Comment: Hi DROP TABLE users, thanks for your reply.
I don't want any C# or XAML Code, just an approach, how to handle such a user control. So, I did not started programming yet.

Comment: @user1011394 it is impossible to tell you a proper approach without knowing what you're already working with. Otherwise just have a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel` of an `ItemsControl` and have your data items have an `int Row` and `int Column` properties that you can bind to `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` in the `ItemContainerStyle` of your `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 1):

For outer `ListView` set `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be `VirtualizingStackPanel` with orientation set to `Horizontal`.

For inner listView, set `ItemTemplate` as ListView.

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Of course you have to tweak a bit template for inner listView as per your needs.